# Rails 4: EOFError: end of file reached following any email in DEVELOPMENT only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, devise

I have rails app which uses devise ofr authentication and sidekiq for background email jobs. All of a sudden, in development only, I am getting the following error associated with an attempt to send an email from the app (e.g. devise forgotten password)

```
     EOFError: end of file reached
```

Strangely the app in production works (heroku set up using sendgrid). I haven't changed any of my development email settings....

```
  ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'slfwalsh@gmail.com'

    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => '@gmail.com',
      :user_name => "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      :password => "xxxxxxxx",
      :authentication => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }

    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

I can't find anything to address this online. Also I note that ALL my apps in development, using similar settings are throwing the same error. I tried a different email address and password (again gmail) and no luck....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are stuck....this worked but I unclear why.

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "myprojectdomain.com",
  user_name: "xxxx@gmail.com",
  password: "xxxx",
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
 }

 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Comment: What did you change in settings?

Answer (score 3):

For those like [Aleksey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551205/rails-4-eoferror-end-of-file-reached-following-any-email-in-development-only/46131763#comment74180120_36604969) wondering how the problem was solved, he added a valid domain. Went from `domain: '@gmail.com'` to `domain: "myprojectdomain.com"`

Answer (score 3):

For me, setting sender email in my Devise config file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have got `EOFError: end of file reached` issue after migration from EC2 to ECS deployment.

Following is short way to diagnose issue.

```
$ telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587
Trying 167.89.118.51...
Connected to smtp.sendgrid.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 SG ESMTP service ready at ismtpd0009p1las1.sendgrid.net
...
```

In case when you don't see kind of `220` greeting from the server after connection, it may mean that something sitting between your client and SMTP server and blocks connection. In our case it was AppMesh proxy which is blocking smtp.

Next test is

```
openssl s_client -crlf -starttls smtp -connect smtp.sendgrid.net:587
```

which should show a lot info about SSL.

If you can't see expected info by this tests check your infrastructure first, neither smtp settings will work.

Note that `587` is standard replacement for `25`. It is expected that client send `STARTTLS` to obtain SSL connection. While another alternative - `465` expected to connect with SSL by default.

More details: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/smtp-connectivity-timeout-issues-ses/

Comment: Switching from 465 to 587 worked for me because 587 was the port specified on my SMTP settings page on sendinblue (the website I use to send emails)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The problem was that I was using the Imap host setting (`imap.gmail.com`) for Smtp host setting (`smtp.gmail.com`).

**Here's how I solved it**:

I simply replaced the host

```
imap.gmail.com
```

with

```
smtp.gmail.com
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps.**